# Different context menu for every TreeView Node

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created context menu for TreeView Node but I face a problem how I can create context menu for different tree nodes?

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom `TreeCell` factory on your `TreeView`. This custom factory will build a custom `TreeCell`, and, this custom cell can define the context menu as expected.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207139/right-click-menu-option-in-the-tree-root-node/18317716#18317716) shows how to create these custom pieces of building blocks :-).